# jQuery quote rotator using slideUp and slideDown

Tags: jquery

I have a quote rotator set up that is displaying two quotes at a time and kind of jumping around all over the place when it should just be rotating smoothly between each one.
I can't figure out what is going wrong. See it in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/RF3xK/1/

Code is below,

```
<div id="quotes">
<div class="textItem">
    testing the quotes testing the quotes
</div>
<div class="textItem">
    asdfdsaf sdf sdf sdf sf sd fsdaf sdf sdaf sdfsd f ds f dsf asdfsdafdsaf asdfdsaf sdf sdf sdf sf sd fsdaf sdf sdaf sdfsd f ds f dsf asdfsdafdsaf
</div>  
<div class="textItem">
    and another one
</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#quotes .textItem').hide();
InOut($('#quotes .textItem:first'));

function InOut(elem) {
elem.delay().slideUp(800).delay(0).slideDown(0, function() {
    if (elem.next().length > 0) {
        InOut($(this).next());
    }
    else {
        InOut($(this).siblings(':first'));
    }
});
}

$('#quotes .textItem').mouseover(function() {
$(this).stop(true, true);
});
$('#quotes .textItem').mouseout(function() {
if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
    InOut($(this));
}
});
});
```

Comment: It seems to be working as intended to me .. what's the problem exactly?

Comment: What is `elem.delay().slideUp(800).delay(0).slideDown(0,` supposed to do? Slide up for 800ms then immediately slide back down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't see a way to fix it with the way you wrote it, so here is a different approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/tFHWf/2/

```
var InOutInterval;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textItems = $('.textItem'), 
        i = 0,
        setInOut = function(){        
            clearInterval(InOutInterval);
            InOutInterval = setInterval(function(){        
                textItems.eq(i%textItems.length).slideUp();
                textItems.eq((i+1)%textItems.length).slideDown();
                i++
            }, 800);        
        },
        pauseInOut = function(){
            clearInterval(InOutInterval);
        };
    textItems.eq(0).show();
    setInOut();    
    $('#quotes').hover(pauseInOut,setInOut);
});
```

Comment: thanks that works well. How would I set it up to have the first one display without waiting the 800ms for it to appear?